# The implication of "consist of"--exhaustive composition?

Tags: implication

I would like to know whether "consist of" refers to an exhaustive composition or not?

For example,

- Their apartment consists of two bedrooms and a bathroom.

Does this sentence mean the apartment consist of these rooms only, or the apartment might include other components?

Thanks,
Leon

Comment: Yes, it does - otherwise it would be '_includes_ two bedrooms'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know whether "consist of" refers to an exhaustive composition or not?

It’s exhaustive.

---

> Does this sentence mean the apartment consist of these rooms only, or the apartment might include other components?

We're only talking about rooms here so other components don't matter in the description. So yes, that apartment only consists of two bedrooms and a bathroom.